# When are the first Python objects 'object' and 'type' instances created?

Tags: python, object, types

Reading: http://www.python.org/download/releases/2.2/descrintro/#metaclasses

A class statement is executed and then the name, bases, and attributes dict are passed to a metaclass object. Since 'type' is an instance - isinstance(type, type), it is an object already. When/how is the very first instance created ?

My guess is that the first instance was created by the core C code and is then 'ready for use' when the interpreter is first started. Am I correct ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is \`object\` an instance of \`type\` and \`type\` an instance of \`object\`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55775218/why-is-object-an-instance-of-type-and-type-an-instance-of-object)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For all intents and purposes, the `object` and `type` objects are created during interpreter startup, yes. In practice, in CPython, parts of the two objects are allocated statically, and parts are allocated during Python startup.