# Why is `object` an instance of `type` and `type` an instance of `object`?

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop, object, metaprogramming

I am a little bit confused about the `object` and `type` classes in Python 3. Maybe someone can clear up my confusion or provide some additional information.

My current understanding is that every class (except `object`) inherits from a base class called `object`. But every class (including `object`) is also an instance of the class `type`, which is an instance of itself and `object` and also inherits from `object`.

My questions are:

- Is there a reason/design decision why `object` is an instance of `type` and `type` inherits from `object`? Has the `type`/class of an object also to be an object itself?
- How can a class (`type`) be an instance of itself?
- Which one is the real base class `object` or `type`?
  I always thought `object` would be the most "fundamental" class, but it seems to be an instance of `type`, which is an instance of `object`, which is an instance of `type`, ...
  Where does this recursion end?
- Is there a possibility to illustrate the relation between the `object` and the `type` class?

I tried looking up the entries of `object` and `type` in the Documentation of the Python Standard Library.

Every class (except object) inherits from object.

```py
>>> for x in object, int, float, str, list, dict:
...     print(f'{x.__name__:6}: {x.__bases__}')
... 
object: ()
int   : (<class 'object'>,)
float : (<class 'object'>,)
str   : (<class 'object'>,)
list  : (<class 'object'>,)
dict  : (<class 'object'>,)
```

Every class is an instance of the class `type`.

```py
>>> for x in object, int, float, str, list, dict:
...     print(f'{x.__name__:6}: {x.__class__}')
... 
object: <class 'type'>
int   : <class 'type'>
float : <class 'type'>
str   : <class 'type'>
list  : <class 'type'>
dict  : <class 'type'>
```

`type` is an instance of itself.

```py
>>> type.__class__
<class 'type'>
```

`type` also inherits from `object`.

```py
>>> type.__bases__
(<class 'object'>,)
```

Also

```py
>>> isinstance(object, type)
True
>>> isinstance(type, object)
True
>>> isinstance(type, type)
True
>>> isinstance(object, object)
True
```

```py
>>> issubclass(type, object)
True
>>> issubclass(object, type)
False
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Answers to all your questions can be found in this book: [Python Types and Objects](https://www.cs.utexas.edu/%7Ecannata/cs345/Class%20Notes/15%20Python%20Types%20and%20Objects.pdf) (could be found also in the: [Wayback machine archive](https://web.archive.org/web/20140928161337/https://www.cs.utexas.edu/%7Ecannata/cs345/Class%20Notes/15%20Python%20Types%20and%20Objects.pdf))

UPD: [another link to the book](https://studyres.com/doc/546727/python-types-and-objects). Let me know if it dies too.

The most important parts to answer your questions:

- Has the type/class of an object also to be an object itself?

Yes, according to the Rule 1 from chapter 1:

"Everything is an object... Any classes that we define are objects, and of course, instances of those classes are objects as well."

- Which one is the real base class `object` or `type`?

From chapter 2:

"These two objects are primitive objects in Python. We might as well have introduced them one at a time but that would lead to the chicken and egg problem - which to introduce first? These two objects are interdependent - they cannot stand on their own since they are defined in terms of each other."

Also Luciano Ramalho in his book "Fluent Python" says that this relation can't be expressed in Python (chapter 21):

"The classes object and type have a unique relationship: object is an
instance of type, and type is a subclass of object. This relationship
is "magic": it cannot be expressed in Python because either class would
have to exist before the other could be defined. The fact that type is
an instance of itself is also magical."

So, for your question:

- How can a class (type) be an instance of itself?

Luciano says that it can't be expressed in Python too.

- Is there a possibility to illustrate the relation between the object and the type class?

Many thanks to the author who made this illustration in сhapter 3:

[image: relation between object, type and other classes]

Comment: Sadly, that image is missing an arrow, to reflect the fact that `issubclass(object, object)` is true.

Comment: @chepner didn't you forget that every class is subclass of itself and it is not special for `object` class?

Comment: But there is an arrow to emphasize that `type` has type `type`. Just wondering why the same emphasis wasn't made for `object` being a subclass of `object`. (That is, every class has a parent class; but `object` is the unique class which is its own parent.)

Comment: The link to the book by Cannata seems to be dead.

Comment: `object` is not its own parent in the sense that `type` is its own class: object is the root, and it have no parents. It is a subclass of itself in the same sense that `class C` is a subclass of itself.  `class C` bases are   `(object,)`, while object bases is empty `()` as seem in a print in the question text.

Comment: Thank you so much - very nice information.

Comment: Arrow type meaning: Dotted arrows decode "is of type" relationship (e,g. `type(object())` is `object`), solid arrows decode "is subclass of" relationship (`list` is subclass of `object`)

Answer (score 2):

According to Python [Data Model](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html), everything in Python is an object and every object has an identity, a type and a value.

`object` is the base class for all objects, `type` is also an object, so it is an instance of `object`, and same for `object` itself. Also `type` is the base class of all object types, so type of `object` is `type`, and same for `type` itself.

This is my understanding, welcome to point out any mistakes.

Answer (score 1):

`<class 'type'>` is the metaclass of class `object`, and every class (including `type`) has inherited directly or indirectly from `object`.

If you need to find more about metaclasses chack out here https://realpython.com/python-metaclasses/

Comment: Thank you! The article was really helpful. But from what I understand now: The `type` class is not a "normal" metaclass as they "cheated" on the implementation level and as it can't be reproduced in pure Python.

Answer (score -1):

I realized it was very similar to instanceKlass and _java_mirror in Java

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).