# Implementation of "type" class in Python 3

Tags: python, class, object, types, instance

I've been playing around with the built-in types in Python 3 for a bit and I've noticed that all classes are instances of the more general class `type`, for example typing `int.__class__.__name__` results in `type`. The same goes for any user-generated class. However, type itself is of type `type` - typing `type.__class__.__name__` results in `type`.

However, this does not make much sense to me. How can a class be an instance of itself? Why is type not an instance of `object`, the most basic class of all? Or is this some low-level magic that is being hidden from the end user?

Comment: Have you read e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55775218/python-3-why-is-object-an-instance-of-type-and-type-an-instance-of-objec?

Comment: I have not seen that question yet. I suppose I can close this question as duplicate now?

Comment: Yes, that post answers my question. It seems I don't have enough reputation (250 supposedly) to mark my own question as duplicate. I'd enjoy if someone else would do that instead.