# what is the difference between type class and object class in python

Tags: python, metaclass

I am learning about metaclass and I see that every class is a subclass of type class in python but sometimes I see people are using object class but object class is also a subclass of type class then what is the difference between them?

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Class vs. Type in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35958961/class-vs-type-in-python)

Comment: `object` is the *base class of everything in Python*. That is what it means when people say "everything is an object*. So it is *always* true if you do `isinstance(x, object)` for any `x`. Explicitly inherting from `object` is not necessary, that will happen by default, so `class Foo(object): ...` is equivalent to `class Foo: ...`

Comment: @mkrieger1 not exactly... that is discussing old vs new style classes. In Python 3, *all* classes are instances of `type`. And *all instance*, (i.e. everything) is an instance of `object`. This wasn't always the case.

Comment: You may notice, there is a circularity: `isinstance(object, type)` and `isinstance(type, object)` are both true! And perhaps even more curiously, `type(type) is type`, and for that matter, `isinstance(object, object)` is true! Read more about this here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55775218/why-is-object-an-instance-of-type-and-type-an-instance-of-object

Comment: "every class is a subclass of type class" - wrong - "but object class is also a subclass of type class" - no it's not.

Answer (score 8):

`object` is not a subclass of `type`: it is an *instance* of type.

`object`, the class, is the root of all class hierarchy in Python - however as everything in Python is an instance, it has to have a "class" that when properly instantiated with the proper parameters results in it.

As it is an obvious "chicken and egg" paradox, after all, the class `type` itself must inherit from object, that part of the class hierarchy is hand-wired in loop: it would be impossible to replicate the same relationships in pure Python code.

And finally: a class being an instance of a metaclass is not the same as inheriting, or being a subclass of that metaclass: inheritance hierarchy is one thing, the metaclass, which is used to construct each class itself, is another, ortogonal thing.

So, to recap: all classes in Python are themselves instances of a "metaclass" - and the default metaclass is `type`. All classes in Python also inherit from `object` - and that includes `type`. The class `object` itself must also be an instance of `type`, and that relationship is hardcoded in the Python runtime source-code (which is written in C in the case of cPython)

Comment: Great... I really wanted to hear this sentence : *"it would be impossible to replicate the same relationships in pure Python code."*