# what is the class of type in python?

Tags: python, class

When I print the class of `type`, I again get the class `type` in console.

```
print(type.__class__)
```

Result: `<class 'type'>`

I am curious if `class` of `type` give `type` for a reason or is it just a way to say that this is the end of class chain.

I tried to print class of type and got the result type again.

Comment: It is the end of the class chain. Otherwise you would have to continue it infinitely with type_of_type, type_of_type_of_type,...

Comment: This question might also be interesting for you: [Why is `object` an instance of `type` and `type` an instance of `object`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55775218/)